# How does one use the 'input/hr' column in the table below in setting up the problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

I have to set up a linear programming problem corresponding to the following scenario:

---

[image]

---

If my understanding of the problem is correct, I use $mod$:

---

Let $i$ be $A$ or $B$.

Let $x$ be amount of raw material.

Let $x_i \ge 0$ be lbs of raw materials of $i$ purchased so $\sum_{i=A,B} x_i = x$

Define the cost of $x_i$ to be:

$$c_{i,1} = \frac{500,000}{2,000} x_i$$

MI yield:

$$m_A := (5,000) (x_A - x_A \ mod \ 5,000) (80\%)$$

Define the cost of $m_A$ to be:

$$c_{A,2} = \frac{100,000}{1} \frac{7}{1} m_A$$

MII yield:

$$m_B := (4,000) (x_B - x_B \ mod \ 5,000) (75\%)$$

Define the cost of $m_B$ to be:

$$c_{B,2} = \frac{175,000}{1} \frac{8}{1} m_B$$

Packing for A:

$$p_A := (15,000)(m_A - m_A \ mod \ 15,000)$$

$$c_{A,3} := (200,000)(10)p_A$$

Packing for B:

$$p_B := (8,000)(m_B - m_B \ mod \ 8,000)$$

$$c_{B,3} := (200,000)(10)p_B$$

Revenue for A:

$$r_A = 400p_A(\frac{1}{1/4})$$

Revenue for B:

$$r_B = 600p_B(\frac{1}{1/3})$$

---

It seems then that our LP has obj function

$$(max) z = \sum_{i = A, B} r_i - \sum_{j = 1,2,3} \sum_{i = A, B} c_{i,j}$$

s.t. the ff constraints:

1. $$x_A + x_B = x \ge 0$$
2. $$x_A , x_B \ge 0$$

---

So is that it? The role of input/hr is in the $mod$ thing I did above? So if we were to solve it, we might have to use [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20181023001619/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53775.html)?

Okay looks too complicated so likely wrong. How do I go about this?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198!2679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_A$, $x_B$ the amount of products $A$ and $B$ (in units) that are produced and $X_A$, $X_B$ the corresponding raw material that you need to buy (in pounds).

You want to maximize profits:
$$
400x_A +600x_B -\frac{100000}{5000} X_A - \frac{175 000}{4000}X_B - 200 000 (x_A+x_B)-\frac{500000}{2000}(X_A+X_B)
$$
(check that all terms are homogenous to dollars)
subject to availability constraints:
$$
\frac{X_A}{5000}\le 7\quad \mbox{(no more than 7 hours on machine A)}\\
\frac{X_B}{4000}\le 8\quad \mbox{(no more than 8 hours on machine B)}\\
 \frac{x_A}{15000}+\frac{x_B}{8000}\le 10\quad \mbox{(no more than 10 hours of packing)}
$$
and don't forget to ensure consistency between variables in units and pounds, with the machine output:
$$
x_A=80\% \frac{X_A}{1/4}\quad \mbox{(check that you have units on both sides)}\\
x_B=75\% \frac{X_B}{1/3}\quad \mbox{(check that you have units on both sides, again)}\\
x_A,x_B,X_A,X_B\ge 0
$$

Comment: Thanks Kuifje. So indeed the only drcision variables here are $X_i$?

Comment: yes indeed! at least thats how I understand the problem.

Comment: okay thanks Kuifje ^-^ I'll go over this later on

Comment: Kuifje, might [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662234) be similar?

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: Okay took me a while to get the 'or'. It kind of looks like $P(A \cup B) \le P(A) + P(B) \le 1$. Again, thanks!