# LP problem involving producing assemblies

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, constraints

I have to construct an LP problem based on the ff scenario that might be similar to a scenario in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662185/how-does-one-use-the-input-hr-column-in-the-table-below-in-setting-up-the-prob) (in the sense that I felt the need to use $mod$):

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

The productivities are minutes per day (as in 8 hrs). For example, if you want to produce 5 part 1's, it could be using 5 milling machines for 20 minutes or it could be using just 1 milling machine for 100 minutes.

---

Note:

1. $8 \ hrs =  480 \ min$
2. $\frac{3 \ min}{drill \ press}(1 \ drill \ press) + \frac{20 \ min}{machine}(5 \ machines) = 103 \ min$
3. $\frac{5 \ min}{drill \ press}(1 \ drill \ press) + \frac{15 \ min}{machine}(5 \ machines) = 80 \ min$

---

So if we let $x_i$ be # of completed assembly $i$'s for $i = 1,2$, then I think we must maximise

$$z = x_1 + x_2$$

where

$$x_1 = (103) [(3x_{1,1} + 20*5x_{1,2}) \ mod \ 103]$$

$$x_2 = (80) [(5x_{2,1} + 15*5x_{2,2}) \ mod \ 80]$$

s.t.

$$3x_{1,1} + 20*5x_{1,2} + 5x_{2,1} + 15*5x_{2,2} \le 480$$

$$|x_{i,j} - x_{k,l}| \le 30$$

where $i,j,k,l = 1,2$ and $(i,j) \ne (k,l)$

---

Okay, what did I do wrong?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the total number processed units, and $y_i$ the number of processed units on mill $i=1..5$.

So you want want to maximize $Z=x$, subject to availability constraints:

$$
\underbrace{\;3x\;}_{\mbox{drill part I}}+
\underbrace{\;5x\;}_{\mbox{drill part II}}\le 
8\cdot 60\quad \mbox{(8 hour working day)}$$
$$
\underbrace{\;\frac{20x}{5}\;}_{\mbox{5 mills part I}}+
\underbrace{\;\frac{15x}{5}\;}_{\mbox{5 mills part II}}\le 
8\cdot 60\quad \mbox{(8 hour working day)}$$

$$
x=y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5\quad \mbox{(all $x$ units must be processed in one mill)}$$

$$
|(20+15)y_i-(20+15)y_j|\le 30 \quad \forall i\neq j \quad \mbox{(no mill runs more than 30 minutes than another mill )}\\
x\ge 0
$$

You need to linearize constraints (3), for example:
$$
|y_i-y_j|\le 10\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad-10 \le y_i - y_j \le 10
$$

Also, it is unclear if these last constraints must also hold for the drill. I assumed not, but if you need to you need to add
$$
|3x+5x-20y_i-15y_i|\le 30 \quad \forall i=1,\cdots,5
$$

Comment: The productivities are minutes per day (as in 8 hrs). For example, if you want to produce 5 part 1's, it could be using 5 milling machines for 20 minutes or it could be using just 1 milling machine for 100 minutes.

Comment: Kuifje, you assumed units/hr right? is that assumption crucial to your answer?

Comment: I have edited accordingly. Essentially you need to make sure your equations are homogenous. If you work with minutes, you need minutes on both sides of the inequality. It should be correct.

Comment: omg thank you very much Kuifje!!! i can't wait to see you surpass me in rep! is the last one supposed to be 30 and not 0.5?

Comment: saw edit. thanks a million!

Comment: Yes you are right! I find these exercise very good. Where do they come from? I checked out the link where they come from, but I mean did your professor make them up?

Comment: Kuifje, really? I don't see how setting up constraints is relevant to OR, but I guess these are good exercises in setting up constraints :P as for course, probably from one of the books in the syllabus. it's in [another file](https://vvcshw.bn1302.livefilestore.com/y3mJcUEPryrSPp7f38i7nUCfFPqWWLWMhwTs7ppY8Jy5_sQTlThqnvedw6JREYao4WxUh4fGbvAKae6wEyKFSCqfSeh2WxkM5tdFAFeBTS9-V8u28BA2Az36bYGVDJ2EyjsoJf-y7WovWdAtUyrGzF6nPKCcoCLakpGKziP9JMukio/ma195j14syllabus_2015second.pdf?psid=1). As for the ones with pesos, maybe made up by him or the other OR profs in the dep with PhDs. he has only a...

Comment: OMG how DUMB of me. I could've just looked [this](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=0X1jMD4mhOoC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22machine+shop+has+one+drill+press%22&source=bl&ots=RKmM63gTBg&sig=xowM3hDgob829GGPCgu-OFHuVLk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjryofimaXLAhVTwWMKHZr5BmwQ6AEIJzAD#v=onepage&q=%22machine%20shop%20has%20one%20drill%20press%22&f=false) along with all the exercises up! THANK YOU.

Comment: I assure you, knowing how to formulate models is very important in OR. Its the only part computers can't do! Thanks for the link.

Comment: ...only a master's so probably he got it from another prof

Comment: I guess so. But I'm thinking I could receive assistance from someone who actually knows about drilling and stuff. Ah well thanks!

Comment: btw my prof said 'For example, if you want to produce 5 part 1's, it could be using 5 milling machines for 20 minutes or it could be using just 1 milling machine for 100 minutes.'...i think he is interpreting wrong, or i am interpreting him wrong